# Remove paths which are subsets of a longer path

Tags: graph, neo4j

I would like to obtain the longest path that are connected to a single parent via Neo4J Cypher query.

My current queries are like this:

MATCH p=(N1:Node)-[REL*..2]->(N2:Node) WHERE N2.RIC =~"some ticker.*" RETURN p limit 50

However,  i am getting results like this

a->b->parent
b-> parent

In my own opinion , i would like to keep only the longest path.
Also, is there anyway to return the direction of the query ? IE: i can see the from/to of a relationship in the output of the query.

Thanking in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the longest path then you can do:

```
MATCH path=(N1:Node)-[REL*..2]->(N2:Node)
WHERE N2.RIC =~"some ticker.*"
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As for getting the directions, this depends on the driver that you use.  In the Neo4j HTTP transaction endpoint if you specify `REST` for `resultDataContents`, it will return a `directions` for any path objects that you return.  Here is how you set that:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-statements-in-an-open-transaction-in-rest-format-for-the-return

Here is an example of what that looks like:

```
      "rest": [
        {
          "relationships": [
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/587"
          ],
          "nodes": [
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1002",
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1001"
          ],
          "directions": [
            "<-"
          ],
          "length": 1,
          "start": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1002",
          "end": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1001"
        }
      ]
```

**EDIT:**

Responding to your comment, in order to get the longest path for each parent:

```
MATCH path=(N1:Node)-[REL*..2]->(N2:Node)
WHERE N2.RIC =~"some ticker.*"
WITH N1, N2, collect(p) AS paths
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
RETURN N1, N2, paths[0] AS longest_path
```

I wasn't sure which side is supposed to be the parent, so I returned both `N1` and `N2` which should give you the longest path for each combination of those two.  You can remove either one to get the longest path leading to/from the node which is left.

Comment: thanks . i dont just want the longest path , i want the longest path of different variations ..


A->B-> C -> parent
D->E->parent

Comment: My cypher: `MATCH path=(n)-[:REL*]->(m) where id(n)=<some id> return path`. I wanted all non overlapping paths. It returned paths: `a->b`,`a->b->c`,`a->b->d`,`a->c`,`a->c->e`. I dont want `a->b` and `a->c` in the output as they are part/subset of other returned paths. How do I do this? Is it doable in cypher?

Comment: You can probably do that, but it would be too complicated to answer in a comment and you're not likely to attract many people to come up with an answer unless you make a question out of that